# New electronic state of matter

Tags: electrons, states-of-matter

I just heard about a new state of matter, clustered electrons. I didn't know that electrons could do that. Can anyone describe the mechanism by which this is possible? https://phys.org/news/2020-02-uncovers-electronic-state.html

Comment: This seems analogous to Cooper pairing in super conductivity

Comment: Take everything you see on phys.org with a grain of salt. The text you've linked to, despite being presented as a piece of journalism, is in fact a press release, i.e., promotional material written by a university press office whose incentives are aligned to get maximum impact and not at all for accuracy.

Answer (score 0):

Just for illumination: I found the [publication](https://science.sciencemag.org/content/367/6479/769) , one has to login, but the abstract clears things up.

> An unusual conductance sequence
>   Effects of correlations between electrons are enhanced in systems of reduced dimensions. The two-dimensional interface between two oxide materials, lanthanum aluminate (LaAlO3) and strontium titanate (SrTiO3), exhibits magnetism and superconductivity. In even lower-dimensional systems fabricated in similar heterostructures, electrons can pair without going superconducting. Briggeman et al. have now observed another exotic effect in LaAlO3/SrTiO3 waveguides: At certain magnetic fields, the conductance in these one-dimensional systems exhibits steps of an unconventional sequence. To understand the experimental data, the researchers used a model that accounted for interactions between electrons and found that the phenomenology was consistent with the formation of a series of correlated phases characterized by bound states of three or more electrons.

It seems an interesting effect. In superconductivity pairs of electrons couple, their added  spins  make a charge 2  boson ( spin 0 or 1). They claim that even though the one dimensional systems  they developed do not show superconductivity, the behavior of conductance can be fitted with a model of three or more electrons making a bound state.

Here is the [wikipedia description](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cooper_pair) of Cooper pairs:

> Although Cooper pairing is a quantum effect, the reason for the pairing can be seen from a simplified classical explanation.[2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cooper_pair)[3] An electron in a metal normally behaves as a free particle. The electron is repelled from other electrons due to their negative charge, but it also attracts the positive ions that make up the rigid lattice of the metal. This attraction distorts the ion lattice, moving the ions slightly toward the electron, increasing the positive charge density of the lattice in the vicinity. This positive charge can attract other electrons. At long distances, this attraction between electrons due to the displaced ions can overcome the electrons' repulsion due to their negative charge, and cause them to pair up. The rigorous quantum mechanical explanation shows that the effect is due to electron–phonon interactions, with the phonon being the collective motion of the positively-charged lattice.

It might be more surprises than phonons exist in solid state.

Maybe someone who has access to the paper could answer .

Comment: If you meanwhile know  more about this topic, I would appreciate a comment. Se my answer to the question.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for asking! I need more information than is provided on the link, but I have personally made a similar finding when I was observing the nature while trying to find confirmation to my idea where the States of matter are derived directly form the speed of light.
I found supporting evidence to the Condensed-Kinetic transition, and also for the Kinetic-Plasma transition. But as I worked out the whole Atmospheric data from Nasa up to a height of 1000 km, I also found another phase transition, which was interesting. Due to the nature of particles above and below this limit, I also named this matter to "Electric Matter". Here is my rude paper from year 2017;

https://www.researchgate.net/publication/312524491_STATES_OF_MATTER_defined_from_The_Speed_of_Light